# Setting content_for misunderstanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, content-for

I'm using this tutorial to set bootstrap modal content in forms, but I want to set the title...

I think I don't understand how to set the title `content_for` method...I understand it for templating, but if I want to send a title to the modal, is it best to make a helper for that? Is there a better Rails 4 way to do this?

Please advise, and remember, I'm not a CE--I've looked at the rails doc and google searched, so please don't demean my question by posting a google link.  Thanks!

Comment: Is 'this tutorial' meant to be a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be rendering the title of the modal dynamically, it's typically better to use a helper method. This will keep your view logic DRY and readable. This method will accept an argument for the title and if none is present it will render a default title.

In application_helper.rb:

```
  def modal_title(title)
    if title.empty?
      "My Default Title"
    else
      title
    end
  end
```

In your modal partial where the title should appear:

```
<%= modal_title(yield(:title)) %>
```

In the view, you will have access to dynamically set the title using content_for. For example, you could pass a string as your title or pass an instance variable from your controller.

```
<% content_for :title, @your_variable %>
```

Comment: Annnnnnd, now I realize I'm an idiot, but that helped.